# How to fix 'datetime.datetime is not implemented'

Tags: python, pandas

I just started using pandas and I was trying to use the pandas_datareader. The program should just get all the data about facebook and then print/plot it.

```
import pandas as pd          
import datetime as dt        
import pandas_datareader.data as data       
import matplotlib as plt       
from matplotlib import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

start = dt.datetime(2019, 1, 7)
end = dt.datetime(2019, 5, 4)

att = data.DataReader('F', start, end)
print(att.head())
```

Everything I get however is this:

```
NotImplementedError: data_source=datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 7, 0, 0) is not implemented
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to specify `data_source` argument to `data.DataReader` function,

see signature

```
def DataReader(name, data_source=None, start=None, end=None,
               retry_count=3, pause=0.1, session=None, access_key=None)
```

so something like this for example should work

```
att = data.DataReader('F', 'yahoo', start, end)
```